# Branch tab is not visible in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Previously, I user to see branch tab in my WebStorm bottom bar something like this (below) but it's not visible anymore:

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to bring it back? I search everywhere but couldn't find any option.

[image]

Comment: Based on your screenshot you do not have Status Bar enabled. Please enable it first as per Vickey's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Git enabled for the project in the Version Control settings?

Can you once again Enabling the Status Bar via the View menu or under menu choose VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration